# how to compare 4 LMER models to measure the difference between 4 groups (2 control groups & 2 research groups)?

Tags: r, anova

I created 4 lmer models, one for each of my studied groups. Then I performed an anova to see if their results differ from each other or not. I got the table bellow with some empty values. I can't see where did I go wrong? I would appreciate any guidance.

```
options(scipen = 100, digits = 3)
df1<-NKurdish
NKurdish.model<-lmer (VOT ~ Gender * POA * Laryngeal * Vowel.Height +(1|Speaker), data= df1)
summary(NKurdish.model)
anova(NKurdish.model)

options(scipen = 100, digits = 3)
df2<-NAmerican
NAmerican.model<-lmer (VOT ~ Gender * POA * Laryngeal * Vowel.Height +(1|Speaker), data= df2)
summary(NAmerican.model)
anova(NAmerican.model)


options(scipen = 100, digits = 3)
df3<-KEFL1
KEFL1.model<-lmer (VOT ~ Gender * POA * Laryngeal * Vowel.Height +(1|Speaker), data= df3)
options(scipen = 100, digits = 3)
summary(KEFL1.model)
anova(KEFL1.model)


options(scipen = 100, digits = 3)
df4<-KEFL2
KEFL2.model<-lmer (VOT ~ Gender * POA * Laryngeal * Vowel.Height +(1|Speaker), data= df4)
summary(KEFL2.model)
anova(KEFL2.model)
anova(NKurdish.model, NAmerican.model,KEFL1.model, KEFL2.model)
```

Result:

```
            npar  AIC  BIC logLik deviance Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
NKurdish.model    26 3252 3353  -1600     3200                    
NAmerican.model   26 3322 3423  -1635     3270     0  0           
KEFL1.model       26 3421 3522  -1684     3369     0  0           
KEFL2.model       26 3558 3659  -1753     3506     0  0
```

Here is a sample of my Data
Note: Group has 4 levels

```
Group   Speaker Gender  POA Laryngeal   Vowel Height    VOT
NKurdish    S1  M   B   VD  H   -108
NKurdish    S1  M   B   VD  H   -159
NKurdish    S1  M   B   VD  H   -140
NKurdish    S1  M   B   VD  L   -136
NKurdish    S1  M   B   VD  L   -137
NKurdish    S1  M   B   VD  L   -115
NKurdish    S1  M   D   VD  H   -108
NKurdish    S1  M   D   VD  H   -109
NKurdish    S1  M   D   VD  H   -148
NKurdish    S1  M   D   VD  L   -101
NKurdish    S1  M   D   VD  L   -130
NKurdish    S1  M   D   VD  L   -123
NKurdish    S1  M   V   VD  H   -141
NKurdish    S1  M   V   VD  H   -125
NKurdish    S1  M   V   VD  H   -129
NKurdish    S1  M   V   VD  L   -118
NKurdish    S1  M   V   VD  L   -117
NKurdish    S1  M   V   VD  L   -119
NKurdish    S1  M   B   VL  H   48
NKurdish    S1  M   B   VL  H   60
NKurdish    S1  M   B   VL  H   82
NKurdish    S1  M   B   VL  L   54
NKurdish    S1  M   B   VL  L   58
NKurdish    S1  M   B   VL  L   58
NKurdish    S1  M   D   VL  H   91
NKurdish    S1  M   D   VL  H   104
NKurdish    S1  M   D   VL  H   82
NKurdish    S1  M   D   VL  L   63
```

Comment: Could you share what the data looks like? Is there a reason to fit individual models instead of including the region as a term in the model?

Comment: I need to report the effect of all variables on VOT within each group as well.

Comment: You can't use AIC (i.e., it is wrong) to compare fits to *different response variables*. If you had used `lmer(..., data = df1)`, `lmer(..., data = df2)`, etc. (which is better practice), rather than `attach()`, you would have gotten a warning or error telling you this. Can you be more specific about your goal in comparing these models to different data sets? I've voted to close this and migrate to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) ...

Comment: if  you want to know if there are any differences among populations, the right thing would be to merge all of the data and test for interactions ...

Comment: I have 4 groups; 2 groups of native speakers (NKurdish & NAmerican) represent reference groups to which I need to compare the other 2 groups of learners(KEFL1 (beginners) & KEFL2 (advanced). The aim is to see whether learners has developed towards NAmerican or not.